# How do I save a .eps at higher than max dimensions in Adobe Illustrator 2019?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, eps, dimensions

I'm working on large wall graphics requiring dimensions that exceed the maximum possible for Illustrator. Is there any way around this while saving the file out as a .eps or .pdf?

Comment: No. Work at scale.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. If everything in your design is vector, then you don't need to do that. Simply create your artwork at something like 1/10th scale. When the job is printed, ask your printer to enlarge it 10 times.